# Old-fashioned use of "because"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In books written in the nineteenth century, you can come across sentences like this (quoting from Ambrose Bierce's The Devil's Dictionary):

> *A Pilgrim Father was one who, leaving Europe in 1620 **because** not permitted to sing psalms through his nose, followed it* [the pilgrim] *to Massachusetts, where he could personate God according to the dictates of his conscience.*

Another well-known writer in whose works I'm certain I found this kind of usage is Jane Austen.

I'm not sure I understand this usage.

Comment: This is (close to?) the nominative absolute construction, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute. What is slightly old-fashioned is the usage of the participle, not of *because*, I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

I see it as a simple case of omission. The longer sentence would in fact be:

> A Pilgrim Father was one who, leaving Europe in 1620 because (he was)
>   not permitted to sing psalms...

It makes sense too and not old-fashioned, archaic or anything. Because the writer is using a V+ing Participial Phrase ("leaving Europe"), it's better to just add another P.P. Participial Phrase ("not permitted").

Comment: «because of not being permitted», too

Comment: Cool Elf, may I suggest you use the Blockquote when answering (the large " on the toolbar). It avoids the horizontal scrollbar when the line is long.

Comment: So does that mean I can't use this in a sentence like this: "I couldn't make it because ill."

Comment: @Brian, thanks for telling me that. I'll try it next time

Comment: @Kaiser, "because" is a Conjunction so it can't be followed by a Noun - or an Adjective like in your example

Comment: @Kaiser, I also have this about your example "because ill" : http://www.coolelf.net/2012/06/because-because-of-thats-why.html

Comment: Okay, so that means it's not used in the same way as "if" and "when" in sentences like "One must wear a helmet when riding a bike"?

Comment: No, it's not used in the same way. Also, the example you cited in your question (especially the part of the Participial Phrase) is practiced in written communication.

Comment: It's not a case of omission. This archaic use of the word 'because' means 'the cause of which' ie. 'the cause of which he was that he was not permitted to...etc'.